# PerformSegueWithIdentifier not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `tableView` on my page and when I press a specific row, my app is supposed to show another page using segue. However when i click on the appropriate row it freezes, and then when I click a different row the segue finally shows up, which is odd. The code used to work for me but for some reason stopped, and I can't identify the issue because the code is identical (at least as far as I can see). Here is a code snippet :

```
func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, loadedFile destPath: String!, contentType: String!, metadata: DBMetadata!){

let title = "This format is incorrect"
let message = "You can only download file that is in .txt format"
let okText = "OK"

let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton)

if contentType.rangeOfString("text") != nil{
        print("this is text")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
    }
    else{
        print("this is an error")
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return;
    }


let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
    print("The file \(metadata.filename) was downloaded. Content type: \(contentType). The path to it is : \(documentsDirectoryPath)" )
    progressBar.hidden = true

let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]


    let localFilePath = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Documents")

    let checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(localFilePath.path!))
    {
        print("FILE AVAILABLE");
    }
    else
    {
        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");
    }

    return

}
```

didDeselectRowAtIndexPath code :

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let selectedFile: DBMetadata = dropboxMetadata.contents[indexPath.row] as! DBMetadata

    let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    let localFilePath = (documentsDirectoryPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(selectedFile.filename)

    print("The file to download is at: \(selectedFile.path)")
    print("The documents directory path to download to is : \(documentsDirectoryPath)")
    print("The local file should be: \(localFilePath)")

    showProgressBar()

    dbRestClient.loadFile(selectedFile.path, intoPath: localFilePath as String)

}
```

The picture below illustrates when I click on the file.txt row. As you can see it just stays grey and nothing happens, but after that, if I click on another file, say enumrec.pdf, it will show the appropriate page. Would be happy if anyone could point out what i am doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Where do you run this snippet? Is it in the completion block of a network operation? If so you need to dispatch the performSegue on the main thread

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry I am not understanding what you mean. I use dropbox api to show the files in the folder (i.e. everything you see on the pic) , is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you post all your code in this view controller class, to help

Comment: @JoeBenton question edited

Comment: I don't see any `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexpath` referenced anywhere in your question.  Where Are you calling this?

Comment: Your symptom describes what happens when you initiate a UImupdate from a background thread. You need to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),...)` to execute your perform segue (and your alert view show) on the main thread.

Comment: @Paulw11 tried Joe's suggestion using the method you described and it didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. The latest is often propose first when using autocompletion, it's easy to make the mistake.

Comment: wow thank you, this actually worked along with Joe's answer. Cant believe it was this, I spent a day on this issue.. thank you so much!

Comment: Next time you will only spend an hour on it and next time you will be the one answering this on a SO question ;)
It's an easy mistake to made but can be very painfull to found.

Comment: Amen to this! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are performing your seque after your data call which is on a different thread (so your app can carry on when your data call is running). When you change UI you have to run it on the main thread otherwise you can have issues like this. Just wrap your performSegue code in this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
});
```

You can read about threads/backgrounds tasks etc here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! Only thing is, I dont think i am doing this right, because i am getting bunch of error when i do this :            `if contentType.rangeOfString("text") != nil{
            print("this is text")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
            }
        }`

Comment: Actually figured it out, you just forgot to add `);` at the end of your code :) And I ran this again, and unfortunately it didnt work for me.